# Trying to match values between an existing table and a created temp table

Tags: case, varchar, temp-tables, case-when

I've built a query that is coming up with some very confusing results.  To start, I have a list of specific codes (varchar) that I have created a temp table using the following format:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MentalDX') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MentalDX
CREATE TABLE #MentalDX (
MHDX VARCHAR(254))

INSERT INTO #MentalDX (MHDX) 
VALUES ('F03.90'),('F03.91')....;
```

There are over 800 values in this table.  When I use the following CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN edg2.REF_BILL_CODE IN (mdx.MHDX) THEN edg2.REF_BILL_CODE
    ELSE NULL
    END AS mdx2
```

I'm always getting a NULL value.  I've used = instead of IN, but it's made no difference.  I know that the temp table works if I create a test query and just replace the column reference with an existing value from the table.  The database shows REF_BILL_CODE is varchar(254) and I made sure to define my temp table column the same as well.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  I can share more segments of code as well, but there will be some items I cannot do to personally identifiable information.

Answer (score 0):

So, my problem was that I joined the temp table in my query.  Turns out the following was actually what I was after:

```
    CASE WHEN edg1.REF_BILL_CODE IN ( SELECT md.MHDX FROM #MentalDX md )  
    THEN edg1.EXTERNAL_ID
    END AS mdx1
```

This gave me back real results instead of all NULL like before.  Now I have a new problem, but will do some more research before asking that one.